# In R Linear Regression , a categorical variable is changed to numeric to build a model. Would that trick work to predict a categorical variable?

Tags: r, regression, logistic, multiple-regression, linear

In R Linear Regression , a categorical variable is changed to numeric to build a model. Would that trick work to predict a categorical variable? Are these results valid? I have seen some R code that uses Logistic Regression for binary variable. However, what if the categorical variable is not binary? ***What about Multinomial Logistic Regression? Would that work or not? Why?*** The data is the following Github link: [Data for this question](https://github.com/illyabjazevic/MLcategorialvariable/blob/main/data.csv)

```
dataset <- read.csv("data.csv", header=T)
dataset$classe <- factor(dataset$classe, levels = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), labels 
=c(1,2,3,4,5))

dataset$classe <- as.numeric(dataset$classe)
mreg <- lm(formula = classe ~ ., data = dataset)
summary(mreg)
```

Comment: I don't think that what you are proposing is much of a "trick". When you code a categorical variable as numeric the software will estimate a simple slope that that variable. If it was categorical to begin with, then this usually would be a nonesense.

Comment: @RobertLong Could this, at least in the binary case, be (like) a linear probability model?

Comment: @Dave OK fair enough, with binary variables there could be some utility, but in general I think it's a very questionable procedure.

Comment: @RobertLong Thank you for your answer! I thought the same. That the code works but the results are wrong. So what would be the right method? I have seen that logistic regression is used for binary variables.

Comment: You're welcome :) There is never any single "right method". There are only methods that are less wrong than each other :)  So if your only motivation is to be able to predict a multiclass categorical variable (ie you are not interested in statistical inference), I would probably stay away from classical regression methods, and use random forest, or perhaps k-nearest neighbour.

Comment: Multinomial logistic regression is a classical regression method, basically logistic regression but with additional outcome categories.

Comment: Yes, you could use multinomial logistic regression.  If your goal was inference, that's what I would have suggested, but for prediction I would go to random forests.

Comment: @Dave  Thank you for your comment! Do you think that Multinomial Logistic Regression would work or not? Can you expand your comment?

Comment: You should ask that as a separate question. Cross Validated works best when specific questions are asked that can get specific answers.

Comment: @RobertLong Thank you for your ideas! May you expand why Multinomial Logistic Regression would work for inference but not for prediction?

Comment: Again, you should ask that as a separate question. Cross Validated works best when specific questions are asked that can get specific answers.

Comment: I didn't say it wouldn't work. It has the potential to work well. But from personal experience I have found random forests to be more useful for prediction of multiclass categories. You should probably ask a new question about that.

Comment: I will ask a new question for sure! Today! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coding multiclass categorical variables as numeric rarely serves any useful purpose in my experience. For one thing, when you code a categorical variable as numeric the software will estimate a simple slope that that variable. If it was categorical to begin with, then this usually would be a nonsense.

If you are looking to predict a categorical variable then you can look into random forests and k-nearest neighbours. If you are interested in inference for a multiclass categorical variable then multinomial logistic regression would be a good option - and you could also use this for prediction, though in my experience random forests do a better job.

Comment: You answer is very good. Would be too much to ask the R code for multinomial logistic regression? I want to learn that. I only know how to do it for binary variables. Or would that be better for the new question?

Comment: No problem. There will probably be several R packages that can fit multinomial models, but the only one I know is `multinom()` in the `nnet` package. But please ask a new question.

Comment: Any package is fine. Thank you for your help! I already published the new question. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/530077/does-machine-learning-algorithms-work-better-than-multinomial-logistic-regressio